# Location is not defined error in React + Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to send some text on basic of hosted URL (where my build is deployed), but I am getting this error:

> ReferenceError: location is not defined

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-mendel-pf54l?file=/pages/index.js) is my code.

```
export const getStaticProps = async ({ preview = false, previewData = {} }) => {
  return {
    revalidate: 200,
    props: {
      //req.host
      name: location.hostname == "www.google.com" ? "Hello" : "ccccc"
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Hello, could you please accept my answer? So that more people could see a solution quickly.

Answer (score 97):

Can you show your imports, because it could be that you are importing router from `'next/client'`

Assuming that you are using functional-based component

You need to import router as follows:

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router";
```

in your function body:

```
const router = useRouter();
```

**Edit, those who're using NextJS v13+**
The router has been moved from `next/router` to `next/navigation`
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router

Comment: 
Thanks this sorted me out. Was an IDE auto-import.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using next js this might occur, if you have a client page and you used useRouter to push the user to another page on that client page so that client page is rendered on server page that let the 'location is not defined' problem/error these problems mostly appears at build time so what you have to do is that in that client page use useEffect hook and let that routing code be in it. like useEffect(() => {router.push('/signin')},[]). this may be fix the error.

Answer (score 3):

The router has been moved from `next/router` to `next/navigation`. It still imports from `next/router`.
Please keep that in mind when working with Next.js 13+.
Additionally, Next.js tries to render it on the server first.
However, location, window, router are client-side.
What helped me was to wrap my conditional in `useEffect`.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Akk1, I modified my answer

Answer (score 1):

`getStaticProps()` is executed at build time in Node.js, which has no `location` global object – [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) is part of the browser API. Additionally, because the code is executed at *build* time, the URL is not yet known.

1. Change `getStaticProps` to `getServerSideProps` ([see documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)). This will mean the function is called at runtime, separately for each request.
2. From the `context` object passed to `getServerSideProps`, pull out the Node.js [`http.IncomingMessage` object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage).
3. On this object, look for the `Host` header.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
  return {
    props: {
      name: req.headers.host === "www.google.com" ? "Hello" : "ccccc"
    }
  };
};
```

**Note:**

- I also changed `==` to `===`, as it's generally advised to use the latter. The former can produce some unexpected results because of silent type conversions.
- I also removed `revalidate`, as this is not applicable to `getServerSideProps()`.